# Showing temperatures with Python (WMI Problem)

Tags: python, windows, wmi

This is my code:

```py
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
temperature_infos = w.Sensor()
#print(temperature_infos)
for sensor in temperature_infos:
    #print(sensor)
    if sensor.SensorType == 'Temperature':
        print(sensor.Name)
        print(sensor.Value)
```

And i get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: x_wmi
<x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217394, 'OLE error 0x8004100e', None, None)>
```

And I think the problem is that I can't add the dll. Some help?

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but generally strings with literal backslash characters in them should have an `r` prefix, like this `r"root\OpenHardwareMonitor"`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output from `for p in w.__Provider(): print( p.Name )` as well as current _OpenHardwareMonitor_ version.